# Concatenate always encrypted columns in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I am trying to concatenate always encrypted columns in SQL server 2016 and I am getting the following exception. Please help...

```
One:

(ISNULL(SGTC.FIRST_NAME, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(SGTC.MIDDLE_INITIAL_NAME, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(SGTC.LAST_NAME, '')) AS CLAIMANT_NAME 

Two:

SGTC.FIRST_NAME + '' + SGTC.MIDDLE_INITIAL_NAME + '' + SGTC.LAST_NAME AS CLAIMANT_NAME
```

And the error message is as follows:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Operand type clash: varchar(50) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_POC_CERTSTORE', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'ALWAYS-ENCRYPT-UIM-WV-DB') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar
```

Comment: Unfortunately, concatenation is not supported for always encrypted columns. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241430/sql-server-2016-is-it-possible-to-concatenate-two-nvarchar-always-encrypted-co

If this is part of an application, you can concatenate the columns in the application after they've been decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation in not allowed on encrypted columns. Currently the only operation possible on encrypted columns is equality. This is due to the fact that SQL Server does not have the key.

You might have to implement this logic in the client application.

From official documentation

> Deterministic encryption always generates the same encrypted value for
>   any given plain text value. Using deterministic encryption allows
>   point lookups, equality joins, grouping and indexing on encrypted
>   columns. However, but may also allow unauthorized users to guess
>   information about encrypted values by examining patterns in the
>   encrypted column, especially if there is a small set of possible
>   encrypted values, such as True/False, or North/South/East/West region.
>   Deterministic encryption must use a column collation with a binary2
>   sort order for character columns.
>
> Randomized encryption uses a method that encrypts data in a less
>   predictable manner. Randomized encryption is more secure, but prevents
>   searching, grouping, indexing, and joining on encrypted columns.